# I am trying to run my meteor app but its giving a bunch of errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Please help me out with this..While running the app it is showing errors. What should I do to fix it up, why are these errors coming?

C:\Users\admin\notes>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\admin\notes ]]]]]

```
=> Started proxy.
=> A patch (Meteor 1.4.2.3) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20161120-00:20:37.659(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\build\p
rograms\server\boot.js:348
W20161120-00:20:37.773(5.5)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20161120-00:20:37.775(5.5)? (STDERR)    ^
W20161120-00:20:37.776(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:37.777(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could
 not be found in your node_modules
W20161120-00:20:37.780(5.5)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following comman
d to install it:
W20161120-00:20:37.783(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:37.785(5.5)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20161120-00:20:37.787(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:37.788(5.5)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.b
abel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20161120-00:20:37.791(5.5)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runt
ime.js:181:9)
W20161120-00:20:37.794(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.j
s:106:16)
W20161120-00:20:37.796(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20161120-00:20:37.798(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20161120-00:20:37.799(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20161120-00:20:37.801(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20161120-00:20:37.803(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users
\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\d
ev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20161120-00:20:37.807(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20161120-00:20:37.810(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
W20161120-00:20:39.759(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\build\p
rograms\server\boot.js:348
W20161120-00:20:39.762(5.5)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20161120-00:20:39.764(5.5)? (STDERR)    ^
W20161120-00:20:39.767(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:39.769(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could
 not be found in your node_modules
W20161120-00:20:39.772(5.5)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following comman
d to install it:
W20161120-00:20:39.775(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:39.777(5.5)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20161120-00:20:39.779(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:39.781(5.5)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.b
abel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20161120-00:20:39.784(5.5)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runt
ime.js:181:9)
W20161120-00:20:39.787(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.j
s:106:16)
W20161120-00:20:39.790(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20161120-00:20:39.791(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20161120-00:20:39.793(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20161120-00:20:39.796(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20161120-00:20:39.798(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users
\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\d
ev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20161120-00:20:39.802(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20161120-00:20:39.804(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
W20161120-00:20:41.575(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\build\p
rograms\server\boot.js:348
W20161120-00:20:41.578(5.5)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20161120-00:20:41.580(5.5)? (STDERR)    ^
W20161120-00:20:41.581(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:41.582(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could
 not be found in your node_modules
W20161120-00:20:41.585(5.5)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following comman
d to install it:
W20161120-00:20:41.587(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:41.589(5.5)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20161120-00:20:41.590(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161120-00:20:41.591(5.5)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.b
abel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20161120-00:20:41.593(5.5)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runt
ime.js:181:9)
W20161120-00:20:41.596(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.j
s:106:16)
W20161120-00:20:41.598(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20161120-00:20:41.600(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20161120-00:20:41.601(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20161120-00:20:41.604(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20161120-00:20:41.606(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users
\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\d
ev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20161120-00:20:41.608(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20161120-00:20:41.611(5.5)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\admin\notes\.meteor\local\
build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try doing

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

Comment: got it worked thanks...

Comment: @Yogit you can one up as well :-p

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens when you update you meteor app old version to 1.4.2.
For fixing this try:-

```
    meteor add babel-runtime@=0.1.13 --allow-incompatible-update
```

got this output:

```
    babel-runtime* downgraded from 1.0.0 to 0.1.13
    coffeescript downgraded from 1.11.1_3 to 1.11.1_2
    ecmascript downgraded from 0.6.0 to 0.5.9
```

After doing this app will be work.